# Should we include anime and manga related travel/tourism questions in our scope?

Tags: discussion, tags, allowed-topics

In light of [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/23280/is-toyosato-elementary-school-open-to-visitors), which asks about the availablity of a real life location that was used as a setting for an anime. I'd like to ask if we should start including travel and location specific questions related to anime and manga.

Currently we already have a few questions about [real life locations](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/20214/is-the-location-of-a-bridge-to-the-starry-skies-hoshizora-e-kakaru-hashi-a-r) in anime/manga. Do we want to expand our scope to allow for questions on real life locations of places that appear or are related to anime. Such as what exclusive things can you get in the [Pokemon Centers in Tokyo](http://www.pokemon.co.jp/gp/pokecen/english/)? Or what things can you do at the [Attack on Titan](https://youtu.be/gy1bDt1fQjE) or [Evangelion attraction](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z5BeaQiMsGM) in Universal Studios Japan in Osaka.

Questions such as those would probably fall under the a [tourism](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tourism) (or otherwise appropriate tag [up to the community]) meta tag. We will have a bit of overlap with Travel.SE, but as we do have a few community members that have been to Japan and could share with a a bit of their expertise. I think it would be worthwhile. Additionally, it would allow us to expand out diversity of questions beyond just anime and manga series.

Of course we'll also have to figure where to draw the lines with these types of question (we don't necessarily want question like what show to I get to X site via Y means of transportation). What do you guys think?

Comment: What about questions concerning anime conventions?

Comment: @Frosteeze we have a conventions tag already

Comment: I'd say that gritty logistical questions are more the domain of Travel.SE, but "high-level" questions like "is Toyogasaki open to the public" or "what $movie memorabilia are showcased at the Ghibli museum" should be welcome here (I imagine Travel.SE would be fine with them too, but we probably have more expertise over here). I think this will be a bit difficult to formalize until we get more anime-travel-related questions, though.

Answer (score 7):

I say we should err to the side of tolerance here. We accept the new topic, and see if we have any significant problems accepting and answering questions on said topic.

If we find that we do not have the expertise or we generally dislike the question, we can always migrate to [Travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 2):

There's definitely a fine line here, but here are some questions to consider (and my suggestions of how to mark them):

- How do I get to { Anime Tourist Location } **Off-Topic (Not our area)**
- What Anime Tourist Locations are there?  **Off-Topic (Too broad)**
- Are there any museums in Japan that showcase < Artist >'s work **Off-Topic (List Question)**

---

- What can I do at < Anime Tourist Location > **On-Topic**
- Does < X Anime Attraction > Differ much from < Y Anime Attraction > **On-Topic**
- Is < X Anime Attraction > Closed down permentantly? **On-Topic**
- Can I book a visit at an anime studio on my holiday? **On-Topic**